# LibGdx: Sprite doesn't move smoothly

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite, move

I'm trying to move an image (300x300px) but it doesn't move smoothly, sometimes it stopped suddenly and then continued moving.

Here is my code in class "MyGdxGame" (extends "ApplicationAdapter"):

```
@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("BG_z1_Moon.png");
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // speed = 200px/s
    x -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200.0f;
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, x, 0);
    batch.end();
    System.out.println(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() + "\tx=" + x);
}
```

I've try to translate camera, use Actor but I got the same result.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: How many FPS are you getting? Try getting rid of the print statement. What is x? If it's an int, try making it a double.

Comment: Well I don't think x is an int when he subtracts a float from it. Have you tried other ways of making the image move constantly like summing the delta and subtracting it in a while loop?

Comment: I had a bug like that once; remove the println command and it runs waaaayy smoother. I don't know why it does that tho.

Comment: @SneakyB Are you saying you can't subtract a float from an int? Because you absolutely can, and improperly doing so will result in exactly the type of error the OP mentioned.

Comment: @Kevin Well that's news to me. If its possible then yeah, that could be the problem.

Comment: @SneakyB Of course it's possible to subtract a float from an int. Please try an example program so you're sure about the advice you're giving before you give it.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the issue. The Java compiler won't complain about you using the `+=` or `-=` operators to add a float to an int.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I get 59-60 FPS. x is a float, making it double and removing print statement doesn't help.

Comment: In that case, can you please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem? Try just using a shape instead of an image, that way we don't need any resources to run your code.